# Proving existence of roots by IVT

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Prove that the equation

$x^5 + 2002x^4 − 2023 = 0$

has at least three real roots.

I am able to prove the existence of 2 roots by taking IVT
choosing the intervals [0.5,2] and [-2,-0.5] proves the existence of two roots

I am unable to prove the existence of one more root. Am I approaching this problem the wrong way or can I still apply IVT to prove one more root?

Comment: Note that if x = y << 0, the the polinomyal is negative, then you can use IVT once more in the interval [y, -2]

Comment: Can you use [Descartes' Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs)?

Comment: Try with $(-2002,-3)$.

Comment: A polynomial of degree 3 has a real root

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace A polynomial of degree 3 has at least one real root.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak Both sentence mean exactly the same, I did not say it was unique

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Generally speaking, people ask mathematicians to be more precise. I had similar problem during a publication in a journal as they did not appreciate the apparent vagueness of the language I had used. It is imperative to use the words "at least" or "at most" whenever there is possibility of ambiguity.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the pigeonhole principle, you can deduce that if $x^5+2002x^4-2023$ has roots 2 real roots, then two of the remaining three can be either imaginary or both real as complex roots come in pairs. If those two are imaginary, then the last one has to be real. Thus, you have proved the equation has at least 3 real roots by only finding 2 using IVT.

Comment: How do you justify talking about “the remaining three”? While any fifth-degree polynomial with real coefficients has five factors, it may not have five (distinct) roots.

Comment: @SteveKass A very easy routine check will reveal that $\gcd(f,f')=1$, where $f$ is the given polynomial. Thus $f$ is indeed separable.

Comment: Yes, that's true and adding that remark would make your answer complete. Otherwise, referring to the "remaining three roots" isn't justified. It's a fine line, as for example the fact that a real-coefficients quintic has five factors could be judged unnecessary to mention, since it's true for every quintic, but something important for answering about the particular polynomial in the question shouldn't be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Analysing geometrically:

As $~x \to -\infty, ~f(x) \to -\infty.$

As $~x \to +\infty, ~f(x) \to +\infty.$

Therefore the graph of $~f(x)~$ must cross the real axis an odd number of times.

As indicated by the comment of MyMolecules, this response is a (very) simplified application of Descartes' Rule of Signs.